# Generalized Fibonacci number

Tags: real-analysis

> Let Generalized Fibonacci number:  $$\begin{cases} a_0=p_0 \\ a_1=p_1 \\ a_{n+2}=Aa_{n+1}+Ba_n \end{cases}$$ Prove that if for $C, D>0$: $|a_{n}|\le CD^n$ then for $R \in (\frac{-1}{D},\frac{1}{D})$ the series is convergent. Then let $f$ - the sum on the entire convergence interval $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$

**My try:**
$$\frac{1}{R}=\lim_{n\rightarrow =\infty}\sup |a_n|\le \lim_{n\rightarrow =\infty}\sup \sqrt[n]{CD^n} = D$$
$$\frac{1}{R}=\lim_{n\rightarrow =\infty}\sup |a_n|\ge \lim_{n\rightarrow =\infty}\sup -\sqrt[n]{CD^n} = -D$$ So: $$R \in (-\frac{1}{D},\frac{1}{D})$$ However I don't know if this prove is good so I please about check.
Moreover I don't know how I can calculate $f$. Can you help me?

Comment: What is the $x$ in $x \in (\frac{-1}{D},\frac{1}{D})$ supposed to represent? Also, what is the definition of $f$ (possibly the sum of all terms, but please clarify)?

Comment: @JohnOmielan  I think it "the series" must be the sum of $a_n x^n$

Comment: @WillJagy That makes a lot sense. Nonetheless, even if it's true, the OP should make this explicit.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Sorry, in my task was $x$ and in my sollution is $R$ but $x=R$, I edited my post. $f=\sum a_n x^n$ for $R \in (\frac{-1}{D},\frac{1}{D})$

Comment: @MP3129 You should edit your post to explicitly state that $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ since not everybody reads the comments. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on the hint provided in the answer by [Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8508/robert-israel), note it is much easier to compare the values of $f(x)$, $xf(x)$ and $x^2 f(x)$ after you first adjust them so they each use an infinite series with the same exponents for $x$. In particular, you can rewrite them as follows:

$$f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+2} x^{n+2} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
$$xf(x) = a_0 x + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+1} x^{n+2} \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
$$x^2 f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n} x^{n+2} \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

With these equations, you can use the recursive definition for $a_{n+2}$ to determine an equation from which you can get $f(x)$ in closed form.

Comment: So have I $f(x)-a_0-a_1 x=xf(x)-a_0 x+x^2 f(x) \Rightarrow f(x)=\frac{x(a_0 - a_1)-a_0}{x^2 + x +1}$?

Comment: @MP3129 You've got the right general idea. However, with your first equation, the LHS is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n+2}x^{n+2}$ and the RHS is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n+1}x^{n+2} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}x^{n+2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(a_{n+1} + a_{n}\right)x^{n+2}$. Equating the coefficients of $x^{n+2}$ on each side gives $a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + a_{n}$. However, your recursive formula in the question gives a difference relation among $a_{n+2}$, $a_{n+1}$ and $a_{n}$. Do you see how to adjust what you're doing appropriately? Also, you may wish to use $a_0 = p_0$ and $a_1 = p_1$ at the end.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about $A$ and $B$ so I have $f(x)=\frac{x(A a_0-a_1)-a_0}{x^2 B+ x A+1}$ Right?

Comment: @MP3129 You're very close now. I also got what you have except that the denominator is $x^2 B + xA - 1$ instead. This is because when you take the $f(x)$ to the other side, it becomes $-f(x)$. Please double check your work to see if it then matches what I got.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see a mistake in my solution...

Comment: @MP3129 Adjusting your original equation gives $f(x) - a_0 - a_1x$ on the LHS, as before, and $A(xf(x) - a_0 x) + Bx^2 f(x)$ on the RHS. Moving $f(x)$ from the LHS to the RHS, and combining the $f(x)$ terms, gives $(x^2 B + xA - 1)f(x) - A a_0 x$ on the RHS. Moving $-A a_0 x$ to the LHS makes it $A a_0 x - a_0 - a_1 x = x(A a_0 - a_1) - a_0$. Dividing both sides by $x^2 B + xA - 1$ gives $f(x) = \frac{x(Aa_0 - a_1) - a_0}{x^2 B + xA - 1}$. Please check how this differs from your calculations.

Comment: Ok, thanks.What do you think about my proof about convergence.Is it good way?

Comment: @MP3129 It seems you're using the root test. Only the first line is required to give the positive value of $R$. The second one doesn't really make much sense as the $\lim_{n\rightarrow =\infty}\sup -\sqrt[n]{CD^n}$ part is taking the supremum of a negative value, so it should be greater than $-D$ and, in fact, may be close, or even equal, to $0$. Instead, as the power series is just in $x$, the region of convergence will be $\left(-R,R\right) = \left(-\frac{1}{D}, \frac{1}{D}\right)$. Does this make sense? There might also be an issue of properly using $\lt$ instead of $\le$, but I'm unsure.

Comment: @MP3129 I believe it should actually be $\gt$ in the initial statement instead. Also, you don't need the supremum. However, I suggest you just use the root test directly to determine the series converges if $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|a_n x^n\right|} \lt 1$. Since $|a_{n}|\le CD^n$, then you know it'll converge if $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|CD^n x^n\right|} \lt 1$. Since $C,D \gt 0$, this limit becomes $D\left|x\right| \lt 1 \; \Rightarrow \; \left|x\right| \lt \frac{1}{D}$, so $x \in \left(-\frac{1}{D}, \frac{1}{D}\right)$. Do you understand what I'm doing here?

Comment: Yes, I really thank you for all the help and answer to all my doubts!! I know everything in this task now.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$, find a relation between $f(x)$, $x f(x)$ and $x^2 f(x)$.

Comment: $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n, xf(x)=f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{n+1}, x^2f(x)=f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{n+2}$. However I don't know how I can continue it.